# Is it possible to use wildcard match with text? if yes how to find wildcard in text using PHP?

Tags: php, string, search, substring, wildcard

i have below string example:

> > many kinds of devices not need repair them and they try etc....

i want find if substring is in this text but using wildcard like examples below:

**de*es**

so it will find **"devices"** or other wildcard cases
like

**de***

**d*v*s**

how can this with php?

i was trying to use fnmatch function, but it not work!

```
$txt="many kinds of devices not need repair them and they try etc....";
if (fnmatch("de*es",$text)) { echo "found";} else {exit;}
```

Comment: You can only use wildcards with Regular Expressions ([preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match)).

Comment: how i can do it with perg_match?

Comment: if you'd read the docs on fmatch(), you'd see it matches filenames exactly the same way that wildcards do at a shell prompt. you'd need `fnmatch("*de*es*", ...)`

Comment: exactly your suggestion was very helpful with using **fnmatch**

Answer (score 0):

i used below code and it work with me , but it need from me to put (* or space) on the two ends of wildcard word to make it work with search in strings.

```
function wildcardcheck( $wildcard, $orginal_text) 
{
    $regex = str_replace(array("\*", "\?"), array('.*','.'), preg_quote($wildcard));
    return preg_match('/^'.$regex.'$/is', $orginal_text);
}

$text="many kinds of devices not need repair them and they try etc...";
$word="de*es*";
if(ltrim($word,'*')==$word) $word=' '.$word; else $word=ltrim($word,'*');
if(rtrim($word,'*')==$word) $word=$word.' '; else $word=rtrim($word,'*');

if (wildcardcheck($word,$text)) { echo "found";} else {echo "not found";}
```